# Find a file in gridfs via md5

Tags: scala, gridfs, casbah, salat

I'm trying to find a file in gridFS via the md5 hash, but don't get it to work.

My app is a Play application, therefore I use [play salat plugin](https://github.com/leon/play-salat). This is what I'm doing:

```
val Images = gridFS("Images")
val image = new File("<some path>/filename.png")
val dbImage = Images.createFile(image)
dbImage.save()

val md5 = dbImage.md5

// now check md5
val result = Images.findOne(MongoDBObject("md5" -> md5)
```

The result is None in my case, but I expect it to be the file previously saved. I also tried:

```
val result = Images.findOne(new BasicDBObject("md5", md5))
```

The file is saved to the db, when I check via cli, it's there. How can I get this file using the md5 hash?